# java11 allows the compilation and execution in a single line

Tags: java, java-11

in a file named filename.java

```
class filename{
public static void main(String[] a){
System.out.println("From filename main method");
}
}

public class ClassName{
public static void main(String[] a){
System.out.println("From First main method");
}
}
```

Observe below commands:

Command 1:

```
C:\javaDJ>java filename.java
From filename main method
```

Command 2:

```
C:\javaDJ>javac filename.java
filename.java:7: error: class ClassName is public, should be declared in a file named ClassName.java
public class ClassName{
      ^
1 error
```

Observation:

command 1 compiles (i assume internally ) and executes successfully.
command 2 throws compilation error.

Problem Statement :

How is java cmd able to compile the file called filename.java, when the file(filename.java) contains a public class (ClassName)which is not named 'filename.java'  (the name of the file-name.) ?

Comment: Java looks for the class with a main method that matches the filename. Other classes are more or less ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight a specific section from the [JEP#Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) with regards to the behavior

> In source-file mode, execution proceeds as follows:
>
> - The class to be executed is the first top-level class found in the
>     source file. It must contain a declaration of the standard public
>     static void main(String[]) method.

Answer (score 1):

The feature which enabled you to execute **Command 1** successfully was introduced in Java 11. The feature allows you to execute a Java source code file directly using the java interpreter. The source code is compiled in memory and then executed by the interpreter, without producing a .class file on disk. Check [this](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) for more information.

The error you got in **Command 2** has been there since the beginning of Java.